How do I load custom class objects from YAML in Ruby 3.2.3?
How do I load custom class objects from a YAML document in Ruby 3.2.3? I am working through Huw Collingbourne's The Book of Ruby and following along with the sample code, but this program does not work as expected.
Here's my YAML file, which consists of multiple documents:
---
- - ichi
  - ni
  - san
- - shi
  - go
  - roku
---
- !ruby/object:Animal
  species: cat
  name: verona
  age: 12
- !ruby/object:Animal
  species: dog
  name: fido
  age: 7

The following code is supposed to print out the two arrays in the first YAML document, followed by string representations of the two Animal objects in the second:
require 'yaml'

File.open('multidoc.yml'){|file|
    YAML.load_stream(file){|doc|
    puts(doc)
    }
}

The nested arrays load, but I get the following error message when it comes to the class objects:
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/class_loader.rb:56:in `path2class': undefined class/module Animal (ArgumentError)

        path2class(name)
                   ^^^^
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/class_loader.rb:56:in `resolve'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/class_loader.rb:48:in `find'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/class_loader.rb:28:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:426:in `resolve_class'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:215:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:30:in `visit'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:6:in `accept'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:35:in `accept'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:340:in `block in register_empty'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:340:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:340:in `register_empty'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:148:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Sequence'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:30:in `visit'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:6:in `accept'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:35:in `accept'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:320:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Document'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:30:in `visit'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:6:in `accept'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:35:in `accept'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/nodes/node.rb:49:in `to_ruby'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych.rb:645:in `block in load_stream'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/handlers/document_stream.rb:19:in `end_document'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/parser.rb:62:in `_native_parse'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/parser.rb:62:in `parse'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych.rb:455:in `parse_stream'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych.rb:644:in `load_stream'
        from multi_load.rb:6:in `block in <main>'
        from multi_load.rb:5:in `open'
        from multi_load.rb:5:in `<main>'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/class_loader.rb:56:in `path2class': undefined class/module Struct::Animal (ArgumentError)

        path2class(name)
                   ^^^^
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/class_loader.rb:56:in `resolve'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/class_loader.rb:48:in `find'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/class_loader.rb:28:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:426:in `resolve_class'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:215:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:30:in `visit'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:6:in `accept'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:35:in `accept'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:340:in `block in register_empty'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:340:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:340:in `register_empty'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:148:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Sequence'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:30:in `visit'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:6:in `accept'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:35:in `accept'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:320:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Document'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:30:in `visit'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:6:in `accept'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:35:in `accept'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/nodes/node.rb:49:in `to_ruby'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych.rb:645:in `block in load_stream'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/handlers/document_stream.rb:19:in `end_document'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/parser.rb:62:in `_native_parse'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych/parser.rb:62:in `parse'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych.rb:455:in `parse_stream'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.2.0/lib/psych.rb:644:in `load_stream'
        from multi_load.rb:6:in `block in <main>'
        from multi_load.rb:5:in `open'
        from multi_load.rb:5:in `<main>'

I've tried loading in the YAML file using the IRB and it appears that the class objects
have not been saved, even through they are clearly visible when I view the serialized YAML data in a text editor.
I have tried swapping out the YAML library for the Psych gem, but I get the same result.
Where am I going wrong? I'm running Ruby on Windows 11.
First time asking a question on here, so please let me know if I've missed anything out.
Thanks in advance,
-I

You seem to be somewhat confused about how this is supposted to work. Your YAML file just contains a reference to the class and doesn't actually serialize the class itself. You still need to actually load the code containing the class before you parse the YAML. Either through require or by autoloading with Zeitwerk.

Thanks for your response - I was indeed misunderstanding (still quite new to this). This has solved the problem, and cleared up the confusion.

Feel free to use that to write your own answer to the question.
